# GlassFish/Payara - Defined maven dependency throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish, maven-3, dependency-management

I am building a small Java EE based web application using maven as build tool. As application server I use GlassFish 5/Payara 5.

The compilation of the current version works without problems, as well as the deployment. Calling some REST endpoints also works fine. Only when I call REST endpoints that use resources from 3rd party libraries - in this case HtmlUnit - I get the following error StackTrace.

I have a direct comparison with a non-EE-based application where this configuration worked fine.

I have examined maven-specific error sources, such as provided/compile scope-tag issue, but I found nothing. In the application itself, the library classes are only called or instantiated, so that should not be the problem.

I suspect an error source in the context of the Java EE framework, but I simply can't find it due to lack of experience.

**Excerpt of pom.xml:**

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.34.1</version>
        </dependency>

...
</dependencies>
```

**Excerpt of StackTrace:**

```
[2019-04-19T19:00:11.284+0200] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1555693211284] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[com.webanalytics.toolbox.api.rest.scraperequest.RestRequestConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.webanalytics.toolbox.api.rest.scraperequest.RestRequestConfig threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1621)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1471)
```

Comment: How do you deploy your application? Does your web archive contain `htmlunit-2.34.1.jar`?

Comment: Yeah, it is in the WEB-INF directory (WEB-INF/lib/htmlunit-2.34.1.jar). I totally have got no clue, what the problem might be.

Comment: I can rule out that it is due to the configuration of the EJBs. If I don't create an instance of one of the htmlunit classes, the application can be deployed and used without any problems. But then the content of this lib is not available to me. Maven also automatically loads all the other libs I need, so this can't be the cause at first glance.

Is there any way I can provide more information to help me get a better picture? Directory structure of the ear file or similar? Meanwhile, I can't find an approach to my research that I haven't already tried.

Comment: Have you tried to put htmlunit jar into glassfish libs folder? Does it work then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. It was because during the maven build process the libs were simply packed into the top level of the ear directory instead of the lib directory. The addition in -tag in parent pom.xml was the solution.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>8</version>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>com.webanalytics-toolbox</groupId>
                            <artifactId>scraper-web</artifactId>
                            <contextRoot>/</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```